# how to add the digital timer to the view

Tags: iphone, timer

i want to start and stop the timer whenever user taps ..

and timer must be looks like "12:34:57" this format ...

any ideas how to build the timer ...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need an UILabel to display the time, an UIButton to start and stop the timer. Arrange them in Interface-Builder and connect them to your viewcontroller.
You will need NSDates to save the startTime and the stopTime too.

If the IBAction for the startButton is activated you save the current time to your startTime ivar, and start a NSTimer which fires every 0.77 seconds or something like that and updates the UILabel. Then you change the UIButtons text to display stop, and if that button is pressed you invalidate the NSTimer and save the stopTime.

The timer method has to split the NSTimeInterval which you'll get with [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate] into seconds, minutes and hours. Which is a pretty basic task. And of course if your timer is stopped you replace [NSDate date] with stopTime.
Some code:

```
NSInteger hours, minutes, seconds;
NSInteger ti = (int)interval;
seconds = ti % 60;
ti = ti / 60;
minutes = ti % 60;
ti = ti / 60;
hours = ti;
NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
NSLog(@"Time: %@", timeString);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach if you need to also calculate days:

```
int remaining = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateTimerStarted];

int d = (remaining / 86400);
int h = (remaining / 3600) % 24;
int m = (remaining / 60) % 60;
int s = remaining % 60;

NSString *timeString;
if (remaining > 0) 
{
    timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d %02dh:%02dm:%02ds",d,h,m,s];
}
else
{
    timeString = @"Expired";
}
```